# GTK application doesn't use system icon theme

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I run GTK application from [examples](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-gtk-3-tutorial/latest/python-gtk-3-tutorial.pdf) of Python GTK usage. The application uses theme defined in the config, but icons from the Hicolor icon theme uses. Other GTK applications (Glade or PCManFM) uses the right themes.

Code:

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf

icons = ["edit-cut", "edit-paste", "edit-copy", "view-refresh"]


class IconViewWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)

        liststore = Gtk.ListStore(Pixbuf, str)
        iconview = Gtk.IconView.new()
        iconview.set_model(liststore)
        iconview.set_pixbuf_column(0)
        iconview.set_text_column(1)

        for icon in icons:
            pixbuf = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 64, 0)
            liststore.append([pixbuf, "Label"])

            self.add(iconview)


win = IconViewWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

settings.ini

```
[Settings]
gtk-button-images=1
gtk-cursor-theme-name=Qogir-dark
gtk-cursor-theme-size=0
gtk-enable-event-sounds=1
gtk-enable-input-feedback-sounds=1
gtk-font-name=Liberation Sans 14
gtk-icon-theme-name=Qogir-dark
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-theme-name=Qogir-dark
gtk-toolbar-icon-size=GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH_HORIZ
gtk-xft-antialias=1
gtk-xft-hinting=1
gtk-xft-hintstyle=hintmedium
gtk-xft-rgba=rgb
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `gtk-icon-theme-name` in the `settings.ini file`, but it might not be loaded correctly in your application.

Lets try to set the icon theme to `Qogir-dark`, you gonna need to change it if is different of course.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf

icons = ["edit-cut", "edit-paste", "edit-copy", "view-refresh"]


class IconViewWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)

        liststore = Gtk.ListStore(Pixbuf, str)
        iconview = Gtk.IconView.new()
        iconview.set_model(liststore)
        iconview.set_pixbuf_column(0)
        iconview.set_text_column(1)

        icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
        icon_theme.set_custom_theme('Qogir-dark')

        for icon in icons:
            pixbuf = icon_theme.load_icon(icon, 64, 0)
            liststore.append([pixbuf, "Label"])

        self.add(iconview)


win = IconViewWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

(kek.py:1216526): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 10:25:51.815: gtk_icon_theme_set_custom_theme: assertion '!priv->is_screen_singleton' failed

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't have to mess with these in your application code, run this in your terminal before running your python scirpt. export GTK_THEME=Qogir-dark